# "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt"

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I am getting a "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt." error when trying to run a webbrowser thread.  I am trying to render a webpage using webbrowser and then scrape it's source code using HtmlAgilityPack.  It seems to work when I run my Unit Tests, but not when I debug or run the source code.  The error occurs at this line:

```
while (wb.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
                Application.DoEvents();
```

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;

namespace Abot.Demo
{
    public class HeadlessBrowser
    {
        private static string GeneratedSource { get; set; }
        private static string URL { get; set; }

        public static string GetGeneratedHTML(string url)
        {
            URL = url;

            Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(WebBrowserThread));
            t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            t.Start();
            t.Join();

            return GeneratedSource;
        }

        private static void WebBrowserThread()
        {
            WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
            wb.Navigate(URL);

            wb.DocumentCompleted +=
                new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(
                    wb_DocumentCompleted);

            while (wb.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
                Application.DoEvents();

            //Added this line, because the final HTML takes a while to show up
            GeneratedSource = wb.Document.Body.InnerHtml;

            wb.Dispose();
        }

        private static void wb_DocumentCompleted(object sender,
            WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            WebBrowser wb = (WebBrowser)sender;
            GeneratedSource = wb.Document.Body.InnerHtml;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your problem is probably `Application.DoEvents`. Try to _never_ use that.

Comment: John is correct that you should never do that in production code; it opens you up to the worst kind of re-entrancy problems. People use `DoEvents` to "solve" their threading problems without realizing that it creates far more problems than it solves.  If you cannot explain what the effect of `DoEvents` is on the Windows message queue and how it interacts with other message pumps then **you don't understand it so don't use it**.  That said, it is hard to say why it is causing the problem you're seeing.

Comment: Thanks you guys are right I used someone's code and I don't understand DoEvents. It seems to run now, but the CPU usage spikes to 100% after a few Webbrowser threads.  I'm wondering if they are even stopping when they should (I have 59 threads running).  Is there a specific way to stop them?  Maybe I should post a separate question...